# Shell script - Sorting 'AWS cloudwatch metrics' json array based on the “Timestamp” property with raw output including statistics

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I am running aws cli
 `aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2010-02-20T12:00:00 --end-time 2010-02-20T15:00:00 --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2  --extended-statistics p80 --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-0b123423423`

the output comes as

```
{
  "Label": "CPUUtilization",
  "Datapoints": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T12:15:00Z",
      "Unit": "Percent",
      "ExtendedStatistics": {
        "p80": 0.16587132264856133
      }
    },
```

How do i get the output in the below format's (2 Columns)

```
19.514049550078127  2020-02-13T20:15:00Z
12.721997782508938  2020-02-13T19:15:00Z
13.318820949213313  2020-02-13T18:15:00Z
15.994192991030545  2020-02-13T17:15:00Z
18.13096421299414   2020-02-13T16:15:00Z
```

with Heading as CPUUtilization (2 columns)

```
CPUUtilization
19.514049550078127  2020-02-13T20:15:00Z
12.721997782508938  2020-02-13T19:15:00Z
13.318820949213313  2020-02-13T18:15:00Z
15.994192991030545  2020-02-13T17:15:00Z
18.13096421299414   2020-02-13T16:15:00Z
```

And in single column

```
19.514049550078127  
12.721997782508938  
13.318820949213313  
15.994192991030545  
18.13096421299414
```

How can achieve this ?

Comment: Use `jq` to parse JSON in bash.

Comment: The sample input is not valid JSON and does not seem to correspond to the sample output(s).  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. Please also bear in mind that the sample JSON can and probably should be edited for brevity and to highlight the task(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input file is `input.json`, then:

To output in the 2 columns format:

```
jq -r  '.Datapoints[] | [.ExtendedStatistics.p80, .Timestamp] | @tsv' input.json | sort -nr
```

With Heading as CPUUtilization (2 columns):

```
echo CPUUtilization; jq -r  '.Datapoints[] | [.ExtendedStatistics.p80, .Timestamp] | @tsv' input.json | sort -nr
```

And in single column:

```
jq -r  '.Datapoints[] | [.ExtendedStatistics.p80] | @tsv' input.json | sort -nr
```

Comment: Is it possible to query the value of the instanceID from the command(i-0b123423423) as a heading using jq ?